# Can this question be now moved to webapps.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, status-completed, migration

Can [this](https://superuser.com/questions/141017/how-can-i-delete-my-account-profile-from-http-forums-asp-net-closed) be now moved to webapps.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 4):

There are no links currently between the existing sites, and the new ones, while they are in beta. As such, it's not possible yet to migrate your question, you will have to copy it yourself, for now.

It is planned, however, as you can see at this [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52141/will-it-be-possible-to-migrate-questions-between-the-trilogy-and-the-stack-exchan) on the main Meta site.